# How to store data for monotouch app when rotation changed?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an app which will call my wcf service to get its data

When the user rotates the iPhone or iPad I will load a different view, however the data will already have been obtained

I don't want to have to go back to the server

What is the best way to store the data to avoid making another call to the wcf service just because the user has rotated the device?

I am using MonoTouch

Paul

Comment: Your problem is not clear. It depends on the way your application is setup and on the size of the data. Can you give code examples of how the views are loaded? Without more information i would suggest to just store the data in a local variable and insert in in the new view when creating it.

Comment: You can pass the data directly to the new view.  You could store it in an application level static class.  You could cache it.  You could store it in a local file or db.  There is no single "best" way.

Comment: There is no code at the moment I am just in the planning stage at the moment. I am new to this so just trying to get my head around it! The data will probably be about max of 1400 objects which have a date and string property. The main thing I am trying to get my head around is the architecture, I.e where would I define the variable you mention for it to be available to assign to the view? There is nothing set in stone regarding the application structure

Comment: Thanks Jason that sounds like a good plan! The comment above was in reply to svn. If I store it in a db I guess I would look to see if its in the database and if it isn't I would use the service

Comment: @Paul: There's no use storing it in database if all you need is to pass data to another view. Just store the data in memory and pass the `List<>` or whatever object you have, to the other view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **MVC** (Model View Controller) pattern (or a similar one) to separate your UI and your data...

Here's an a [guide](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Hello,_MVC) on how to do this using MonoTouch.